# Compile Error thrown when calling blpapicomLib2

Tags: excel, bloomberg, vba

Here is the beginning of my class module:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents session As blpapicomLib2.session
Private cid As blpapicomLib2.CorrelationId

Dim subFields As Variant
Dim securitiesArray() As String
```

These five lines are *straight* from the Bloomberg API example files. If I open the example spreadsheet and run the sub in question, it's fine. If I copy the code into another VBA editor in a new workbook, I get the "Compile Error: User-defined type not defined," with the second line highlighted. If I comment it out, same error is thrown except the first line is then highlighted.

I'm very confused. Is there a reference outside of the code I'm forgetting to make?

Comment: Add a reference to the Bloomberg API.

Comment: As far as I know, I have a reference to the API. Where can I check that?

Comment: Tools->References... from the menu.

Comment: Thanks very much. That was it.

Comment: @mattsurw You can answer your question in the answer section below so that future users can benefit from your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a reference to the Bloomberg API, which I was able to change under in the references menu (Tools->References). Smooth sailing after that.